How to Set a Different Decimal Separator for a Specific Application in Windows 11?
I have successfully changed the decimal separator for the entire Windows system by following the instructions in this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/decimal-separator-changes-after-update-to-windows/02aa8cd9-1048-403d-be41-91cfb0dc3830
However, my goal is to maintain the Brazilian comma as the decimal separator for most applications while configuring a specific software to use the dot as the decimal separator. Is there a way to apply this setting to just one application without affecting the rest of the system settings?

I have a suspicion if you want to set a single application to do something different than the system's settings, it would require a change in the application itself.

@keltari, the application is old and the author is not updating it anymore, unfortunately.

You might not be able to accomplish this, most Windows developers, use the regional settings of the user instead of offering their own regional preferences. Windows only allows you to set the user’s region and the system’s default user region.
